# Number of Eigenvectors of a Hermitian Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Non mathematician/physics student asking.
I've been learning quantum mechanics from The Theoretical Minimum, and in it the author has made a claim that the Eigenvectors of a Hermitian operator form an orthonormal basis. I have understood that if the eigenvalues corresponding to two eigenvectors are unequal then the two eigenvectors must be orthogonal. I've even understood that if two eigenvectors have equal eigenvalues, we can find two eigenvectors which are linear combinations of the two former eigenvectors with the same eigenvalue. I now need to prove that for a matrix of the nth order there are exactly n linearly independent eigenvectors. Can someone help me with this part?

Comment: Are you convinced that linear combination of degenerate eigenvectors can be formed to make a set of mutually orthogonal eigenvectors?

Comment: @aneetkumar yes, something called the Graham smidth procedure can be used to make orthogonal eigenvectors as linear combinations of Eigenvectors with the same eigenvalues

Comment: In that case, you know that all eigenvectors are orthogonal. You already answered your question